# sas expanding the code to multiple columns using lag function and performing an operation

Tags: sas

My dataset is like this

```
bucket  D_201009    D_201010    D_201011    D_201012    D_201101    D_201102    D_201103
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0
2   3   0   3   0   1   6   3
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   4   0   0   0   0   0
5   4   0   4   0   4   8   1
6   8   0   8   0   8   10  8
7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
8   7   0   7   0   0   7   3
```

what I want is this

```
bucket  D_201009    D_201010    D_201011    D_201012    D_201101    D_201102    D_201103
0   23  4   22  0   14  31  15
1   23  4   22  0   14  31  15
2   22  4   22  0   13  31  15
3   19  4   19  0   12  25  12
4   19  4   19  0   12  25  12
5   19  0   19  0   12  25  12
6   15  0   15  0   8   17  11
7   7   0   7   0   0   7   3
8   7   0   7   0   0   7   3
```

where the sum is the value for bucket 0 and 1 row the corresponding bucket 2 for column D_201009 =sum-original value(1)  and later for bucket 3 for column D_201009 previous value(lag value) -3(value original) and label this column as original column name. I wrote the code to perform one column.

```
data test;
input bucket D_201009 D_201010 D_201011 D_201012 D_201101 D_201102 D_201103;
datalines;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
2 3 0 3 0 1 6 3
3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
4 0 4 0 0 0 0 0
5 4 0 4 0 4 8 1
6 8 0 8 0 8 10 8
7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
8 7 0 7 0 0 7 3
;
run;
```

## Saving these column names in a macro

```
proc contents data = test
out = vars(keep = varnum name)
noprint;
run; 
proc sql noprint;
select distinct name
into :orderedvars2 separated by ' '
from vars
where varnum >=2
order by varnum;
quit;
```

## Finding sum of one column only

```
proc sql;
select sum(D_201009) into :total from test;
quit;
```

## Using lag to perform

```
data result(drop= D_201009 lag_D_201009 rename=(sum=D_201009));
set test;
retain sum;
if bucket < 2 then sum = &total;
sum = sum(sum, -lag(D_201009));
run;
```

how do I change the code to work for all columns where the column names are stored as macro &orderedvars2. ?

Answer (score 2):

The way I'd approach it would be to transpose the data structure to a more useful data structure; then you don't have to use macro variables.  You can use BY processing instead, and no lags.

The way I create the final output is to transpose the initial dataset so you have one row per bucket/D_var, then sort by the D_vars (_NAME_ holds that).  Then use a Double DoW loop in order to first calculate the sum, and then to subtract the value.  Note I don't have to use Retain or Lag here, I can just directly operate on the value since I'm in a DoW loop.  I output *before* subtracting since that's what you seem to want.  Then I retranspose back.

This might not be the fastest option if you have very large data, since it goes through several steps; if you do, you should be using a more efficient algorithm anyway.  But it's likely the least fiddly if you don't always have the same columns.

```
proc transpose data=test out=test_t;
by bucket;
run;

proc sort data=test_t;
  by _name_ bucket;
run;

data want_t;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last._name_);
    set test_t;
    by _name_ bucket;
    sum_var = sum(sum_var,col1);
  end;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last._name_);
    set test_t;
    by _name_ bucket;
    output;
    sum_var = sum_var - col1;
  end;
run;

proc sort data=want_t;
by bucket _name_;
run;
proc transpose data=want_t out=want;
  by bucket;
  id _name_;
  var sum_var;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use proc summary to get sum of each variable, then define multiple arrays.

```
proc summary data=test;
var D:;
output out=sum(drop=_:) sum=/autoname;
run;

data want;
   set test;
   if _n_=1 then set sum;
   array var1 D_201009--D_201103;
   array var2 D_201009_sum--D_201103_sum;
   array var3 _D_201009 _D_201010 _D_201011 _D_201012 _D_201101 _D_201102 _D_201103;
   array temp (7) _temporary_;
   retain temp;
   do i=1 to dim(var1);
      lag=lag(var1(i));
      if bucket<2 then var3(i)=var2(i);
      else var3(i)=sum(temp(i),-lag);
      temp(i)=var3(i);
   end;
   drop D: lag i;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this right you want to sum the column and then subtract the value of each observation from the total?

Getting totals is easy, just use `proc summary`.

Then combine it with the original data.  Here is a way that will work without having to worry about the actual variable names. In this program it will sum all variables that start with `d_` but you could use any variable list you want.  If you have more than 100 variables then change the dimension of the temporary array.

```
%let varlist=d_:;

* Get sums into variables with same names ;
proc summary data=have ;
  var &varlist ;
  output out=total sum=  ;
run;

data want ;
  set have(obs=0) /* Set variable order */
      total(keep=&varlist) /* Get totals */
      have(keep=&varlist)  /* Get lagged variables */
  ;
  array vars &varlist ;
  array total (100) _temporary_;
  set have (drop=&varlist);  /* Get non-lagged variables */
  do i=1 to dim(vars);
    if _n_>1 then vars(i)=total(i)-vars(i);
    total(i)=vars(i);
  end;
  drop i;
run;
```

If you have missing values you might want to add this line of code at beginning of the DO loop:

```
vars(i)=coalesce(vars(i),0);
```